# Getting on-prem Docker logs to Azure log analytics

Tags: azure, docker, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm working in a hybrid cloud environment where we have the majority of our infrastructure in Azure, but we have some on premises machines that we also want to monitor and aggregate their log data into the same log analytics workspace.

I've successfully installed the [OMS Agent for Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux) and I can see that at least performance metrics and heartbeat is being collected from our local machine after following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-linux-computer#collect-event-and-performance-data). However, I can't find any guidance on how to get logs from Docker containers from on-prem to cloud.

On the on-prem machines we are running Docker, no clusters. We have some IoT Edge modules that are being managed and deployed through the IoT Hub, although I guess it is the same procedure to collect these logs since it is still Docker.

How should I got about getting my Docker logs to log analytics using the OMS agent? Is the OMS agent what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my own error. When I reinstalled the agent I could see in the logs that the Docker version was too old for the agent to handle, so it was skipped. Updated Docker and it works.

Comment: Where did you find the log that showed you that.  It might be my issue also.

Comment: @MikeF I think it was when running the install script